# Create an array of objects that implements a specific protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

**TL;DR**

I'm looking for an array type (`var array = [TheTypeImLookingFor]()`) like 'all objects that subclasses `UIViewController` **and** implements the protocol `MyProtocol`.

**Explanation**

I'm building a kind of wizard view with a container view and embedded child views (controller). No problem, this will work as long, as I have only one `base` type of child view controllers.

Due to the content of screens, I have now a bunch of view controllers of type `MyTableViewController` which is a subclass of `UITableViewController` and other view controllers that have regular `UIViewControllers` as base.

All of the view controllers have one thing in common. A default data property `myData: MyObject`.

I created a protocol `MyProtocol` that contains this property.

Now, I have to combine all this view controllers into one array to use it as wizard steps. As long as I only have to access the view controller methods (array items are type of `UIViewController`) I'm able to use `var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()` or if I wanna only access the `myData` property, I change the array item type to `MyObject`.

But the problem is, I have to access the methods from the `UIViewController` and from the protocol.

That's why I'm looking for an array type like 'all objects that subclasses `UIViewController` **and** implements the protocol `MyProtocol`.

I tried:

- `var viewControllers = [UIViewController: MyProtocol]()` // is a dict
- `var viewControllers = UIViewController where MyProtocol
- `var viewControllers = UIViewController.conforms(to: MyProtocol)
- ...

But nothing works as expected.

Comment: Do the elements of the array *have* to be typed as both `UIViewController` and `MyProtocol`? Otherwise you could just stick the methods from `UIViewController` that you require in `MyProtocol` (or create a separate protocol for them and use protocol composition).

Comment: Yep, they have to be both. Maybe my idea of the implementation is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's currently no way to type something so that it describes anything which inherits from a given class *and* conforms to a given protocol.

One possible hacky workaround would be to just create a wrapper type in order to perform typecasting for you in the case that you need to treat the instance as a `MyProtocol`.

```
struct MyProtocolViewController {

    let base: UIViewController

    init<T : UIViewController>(_ base: T) where T : MyProtocol {
        self.base = base
    }

    func asMyProtocol() -> MyProtocol {
        return base as! MyProtocol
    }
}
```

Now you can create a `[MyProtocolViewController]`, and can either treat an element as a `UIViewController`, or a `MyProtocol`.

```
// given that ViewController and AnotherViewController conform to MyProtocol.
let viewControllers = [MyProtocolViewController(ViewController()),
                       MyProtocolViewController(AnotherViewController())]

for viewController in viewControllers {
    print(viewController.asMyProtocol().myData)
    print(viewController.base.prefersStatusBarHidden)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! You helped me with your ideas a lot. At the moment I work with 2 arrays one for the uncasted `UIViewController` objects and one for the casted (to the protocol) objects. This is ugly and stupid but it works at the moment.

Comment: @Tobonaut I wouldn't recommend using parallel arrays for this, although I do admit that there doesn't seem to be any 'perfect' solution to it.

Comment: hm, ok. Do you think I have the wrong "thoughts" about this? I'm a former Java EE developer and maybe I use the wrong pattern.

Comment: @Tobonaut Parallel arrays are generally considered to be an anti-pattern due to the fact that it makes it difficult to keep them in sync, and it separates data which should be together (e.g your controller typed as a `UIViewController` and a `MyProtocol`). It's nearly always preferable to contain these in a suitable data structure, such as a struct.

Comment: That sounds like a practical idea. I'll try it later. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use protocol composition with a placeholder protocol for the class:

```
protocol UIViewControllerClass {}
extension UIViewController: UIViewControllerClass {}

protocol MyProtocol:class {}

class MySpecialVC:UIViewController,MyProtocol {}    

var viewControllers = [UIViewControllerClass & MyProtocol]()

viewControllers.append( MySpecialVC() )
```

This covers the type safety part but doesn't let you access UIViewController methods without type casting.   You can reduce the type casting ugliness by adding a typed property to your protocol (when it applies to the base class)

```
extension MyProtocol where Self: UIViewControllerClass
{
   var vc:UIViewController { return self as! UIViewController }
}

// accessing the view controller's methods would then only require insertion of a property name.
viewControllers.first!.vc.view
```

Alternatively, you could define the UIViewController methods you need to call in the placeholder protocol but that could quickly become tiresome and redundant if you're going to use many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create :

Why not creating :

```
class ObservingViewController : UIViewController, MyProtocol {


}

var viewControllers : [ObservingViewController] = []
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants the elements of this array to know that they are also subclass objects of `UIViewController`, which will not be the case if only working with typed protocol objects.

Comment: Yep, @dfri. That's my problem.

Comment: One of OP's classes inherits from `UITableViewController`, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a `protocol` that defines all the `UIViewController` functions that you need. Make sure that you copy the method signature, otherwise you will have to implement the functions again.

```
protocol UIViewControllerInteractions {
    //copy the signature from the methods you want to interact with here, e.g.
    var title: String? { get set }
}
```

Then, you can extend your existing protocol.

```
protocol MyProtocol: UIViewControllerInteractions { }
```

Or create a new protocol that extends `UIViewControllerInteractions` and `MyProtocol`.

```
protocol MyProtocolViewController: UIViewControllerInteractions, MyProtocol { }
```

Now, when you extend your `SubclassUIViewController`, you still only have to add your `myData` because the methods in the `UIViewControllerInteractions` are already implemented by `UIViewController` (that's why we copied the method signature)

```
class SubclassUIViewController: MyProtocol {
    var myData ...
}
```

You can now have an `array` of `MyProtocol` or `MyProtocolViewController` and also call the methods defined in `UIViewControllerInteractions` which will call the `UIViewController` methods.

```
var viewController: [MyProtocol] = [...]
viewController.forEach { (vc) in
    print(vc.myData)
    print(vc.title)
}
```

Comment: [OP says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090028/create-an-array-of-objects-that-implements-a-specific-protocol#comment71351002_42090028) they need to be able to use the array's elements as `UIViewController` typed instances – I had the same thought too :)

Comment: I missed that part. Thanks :) Maybe this helps someone else with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it with a custom base class. Imagine an array like:

```
var viewControllers: [MapViewController]
```

which all should extend from `UIViewController` and implement the following protocol:

```
protocol MapViewControllerDelegate {
    func zoomToUser()
}
```

Then I've declared a base class like:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: MapViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

Caution: this class doesn't implement the above protocol but holds a property which provides the desired functionality. The next step is to define one of the `UIViewController` that will be added to the array:

```
class GoogleMapsViewController: MapViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
}

extension GoogleMapsViewController: MapViewControllerDelegate {
    func zoomToUser() {
        // Place custom google maps code here
    }
}
```

The important part is located in the viewDidLoad method. The view controller assigns itself as the delegate.

**Usage:**

```
let googleMapsViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoogleMapsViewController") as! GoogleMapsViewController
let mapboxMapsViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapboxMapsViewController") as! MapboxMapsViewController
let mapViewControllers: [MapViewController] = [googleMapsViewController, mapboxViewController]
for mapVC in mapViewControllers {
    mapVC.delegate?.zoomToUser()
}
```

**The benefits:**

- The `MapViewController` is like an abstract class and If I change the MapViewControllerDelegate the compiler forces me to implement the changes in the `GoogleMapsViewController` and in the `MapboxMapsViewController`.
- If I need a second protocol I could just implement a second delegate property.
- No type casting needed like in the other answers. Each `UIViewController` is still a `UIViewController` and provides all its methods.