# Swift Typealias for Class and Protocol

Tags: swift, types

I have a variable that must be a `UIView` that also implements the protocol `MTMathKeyboard`.

I've tried,

```
var keyboard: (UIView & MTMathKeyboard)
var keyboard: UIView<MTMathKeyboard>
```

What's the syntax for a non-generic class instance that implements a protocol?

Comment: I think there is no simple solution for this yet in Swift. Check out this blog post: http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/classes-and-protocols/

Comment: Related (duplicate?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623761/swift-property-with-type-and-protocol

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42090028/2976878

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4 you can use:

```
let keyboard: UIView & MTMathKeyboard
```

Comment: very helpful, what's the name of this feature? I've been looking for documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should go this way:

```
protocol MTMathKeyboard: class {

}

class YourClass<MTMathKeyboard where T:UIView> {
    var keyboard: T!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use protocol composition and extend UIView to meet a placeholder protocol:

```
protocol UIViewClass {}
extension UIView:UIViewClass {}


var keyboard :  UIViewClass & MTMathKeyboard
```

Answer (score -1):

```
typealias KeyboardView = UIView & MTMathKeyboard

protocol MTMathKeyboard: class {
}

private func updateController(with view: KeyboardView) {
        someView = view
}
```

Comment: a good example why sticking to code formatting guidelines is helpful: `someView = keyboard` here an object called `keyboard` does not exists, but it is a type name.